# How to make a cycle with this code?

Tags: c#, sql, excel

Well, I have the next code:

```
    private void Btn_Importar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\archivos de excel\\238.xls; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes\"";
        OleDbConnection origen = default(OleDbConnection);
        origen = new OleDbConnection(conexion);
        OleDbCommand seleccion = default(OleDbCommand);
        seleccion = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [238$]", origen);
        OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        adaptador.SelectCommand = seleccion;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adaptador.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        origen.Close();
        SqlConnection conexion_destino = new SqlConnection();
        conexion_destino.ConnectionString = "Data Source =USUARIO-PC\\SQLEXPRESSS;Initial Catalog=Dentista; Integrated Security=True";
        conexion_destino.Open();
        SqlBulkCopy importar = default(SqlBulkCopy);
        importar = new SqlBulkCopy(conexion_destino);
        importar.DestinationTableName = "Tabla_238";
        importar.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[0]);
        conexion_destino.Close();
        // MessageBox.Show("Se ha importado su archivo con éxito!");



    }
```

I need to import 23,000 excel files into SQL with C# and I do not want to do it one by one, can you help me, please?

I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get all exel file in the path with this code

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\archivos de excel\\", "*.xls");
```

and set FoeEach on filePaths , and finally use dynamic connection

```
string conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\archivos de excel\\"+filename+"; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes\"";
```

Comment: Oh thank you! but How can I increment or change at the same time the "238.xls" , [238$]  and Tabla_238 ? like increase only the number?

Comment: @JesusCamacho you should concat variable to string ! its easy such as : importar.DestinationTableName = "Table_"+numberVariable ; and the you can change it ...

Comment: ooooh great! Thank you so much!